# Clicking an empty space in gnome-terminal selects the whole line

Tags: suse, gnome-terminal, vnc-server

I have a very frustrating problem: left-clicking an empty space in gnome-terminal selects the whole (empty) line.
This pretty much kills all the copy-paste functionality of gnome - in order to copy from one window to another I need to change focus to the other window, and just changing the focus selects the empty space and clears the previous selection.

More details:

- I'm connecting to a Linux machine through VNC.
  Same problem happens with different VNC clients.
- Linux Distro: SLES 11 SP2 (i586)
- Linux machine is a virtual machine on top of VMWare ESXi
- VNC Server: TightVNC Server version 1.3.9

I found the description of same problem on [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1354642), but there was no resolution posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to answer my own question, in case anyone is interested in this issue.
The problem was unsolvable in the existing setup - I tried every possible solution I could find on the web.

Changing VNC Server helped.

Looks like it's a problem of TightVNC Server (or maybe of this particular version of the TightVNC).
With other servers (e.g. RealVNC) everything works fine.